# Response menu not collapsing and reloads page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

At http://www.dentalo.se/contact it is using a responsive menu for mobile devices.

When clicking on the menu button it collapses the menu but the same time reloads the page.

Can anyone tell my why and how I can fix it?

[image]

Thanks for the time you are taking to help me.

Edit

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- BEGIN RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle btn navbar-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- END RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
            <!-- BEGIN LOGO (you can use logo image instead of text)-->
            <a class="navbar-brand logo-v1" href="/">
                <img src="/assets/img/logo_blue.png" id="logoimg" alt="">
            </a>
            <!-- END LOGO -->
        </div>

        <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li id="MainMenuHome"><a href="/">Start</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown" id="MainMenuDentalo">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="0" data-close-others="false" href="#">
                        Dentalo
                        <i class="icon-angle-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li id="SubMenuAbout"><a href="/about">Om Dentalo</a></li>
                        <li id="SubMenuJob"><a href="/job">Lediga tjänster</a></li>
                        <li id="SubMenuConnect"><a href="/connect">Anslut</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="MainMenuLogIn"><a href="/login">Logga in</a></li>
                <li id="MainMenuContact"><a href="/contact">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li class="menu-search">
                    <span class="sep"></span>
                    <i class="icon-search search-btn"></i>

                    <div class="search-box">
                        <form action="#">
                            <div class="input-group input-large">
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" placeholder="Sök..." CssClass="form-control" ID="textBoxSearch"></asp:TextBox>
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn theme-btn" ID="ButtonSearch" OnClick="ButtonSearch_Click" Text="Sök" />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div> 
                </li>
            </ul>                           
        </div>
        <!-- BEGIN TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
/*
 * Project: Twitter Bootstrap Hover Dropdown
 * Author: Cameron Spear
 * Contributors: Mattia Larentis
 *
 * Dependencies?: Twitter Bootstrap's Dropdown plugin
 *
 * A simple plugin to enable twitter bootstrap dropdowns to active on hover and provide a nice user experience.
 *
 * No license, do what you want. I'd love credit or a shoutout, though.
 *
 * http://cameronspear.com/blog/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-on-hover-plugin/
 */
;(function($, window, undefined) {
    // outside the scope of the jQuery plugin to
    // keep track of all dropdowns
    var $allDropdowns = $();

    // if instantlyCloseOthers is true, then it will instantly
    // shut other nav items when a new one is hovered over
    $.fn.dropdownHover = function(options) {

        // the element we really care about
        // is the dropdown-toggle's parent
        $allDropdowns = $allDropdowns.add(this.parent());

        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                $parent = $this.parent(),
                defaults = {
                    delay: 500,
                    instantlyCloseOthers: true
                },
                data = {
                    delay: $(this).data('delay'),
                    instantlyCloseOthers: $(this).data('close-others')
                },
                settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options, data),
                timeout;

            $parent.hover(function(event) {
                // so a neighbor can't open the dropdown
                if(!$parent.hasClass('open') && !$this.is(event.target)) {
                    return true;
                }

                if(shouldHover) {
                    if(settings.instantlyCloseOthers === true)
                        $allDropdowns.removeClass('open');

                    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
                    $parent.addClass('open');
                }
            }, function() {
                if(shouldHover) {
                    timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
                        $parent.removeClass('open');
                    }, settings.delay);
                }

            });

            // this helps with button groups!
            $this.hover(function() {
                if(shouldHover) {
                    if(settings.instantlyCloseOthers === true)
                        $allDropdowns.removeClass('open');

                    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
                    $parent.addClass('open');
                }
            });

            // handle submenus
            $parent.find('.dropdown-submenu').each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var subTimeout;
                $this.hover(function() {
                    if(shouldHover) {
                        window.clearTimeout(subTimeout);
                        $this.children('.dropdown-menu').show();
                        // always close submenu siblings instantly
                        $this.siblings().children('.dropdown-menu').hide();
                    }
                }, function() {
                    var $submenu = $this.children('.dropdown-menu');
                    if(shouldHover) {
                        subTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
                            $submenu.hide();
                        }, settings.delay);
                    } else {
                        // emulate Twitter Bootstrap's default behavior
                        $submenu.hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    };

    // helper variables to guess if they are using a mouse
    var shouldHover = false,
        mouse_info = {
            hits: 0,
            x: null,
            y: null
        };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // apply dropdownHover to all elements with the data-hover="dropdown" attribute
        $('[data-hover="dropdown"]').dropdownHover();

        // if the mouse movements are "smooth" or there are more than 20, they probably have a real mouse
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
            mouse_info.hits++;
            if (mouse_info.hits > 20 || (Math.abs(e.pageX - mouse_info.x) + Math.abs(e.pageY - mouse_info.y)) < 4) {
                $(this).unbind(e);
                shouldHover = true;
            }
            else {
                mouse_info.x = e.pageX;
                mouse_info.y = e.pageY;
            }
        });
    });

    // for the submenu to close on delay, we need to override Bootstrap's CSS in this case
    var css = '.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu{display:none}';
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }
    $('head')[0].appendChild(style);
})(jQuery, this);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your `button` element (`navbar-btn`) is submitting your form. Try adding type="button" to the button element.

Also in the click event handler you can also try to add `e.preventDefault()` to your click event handler.

I cant seem to find the JavaScript from the click event of your button so I can help much more. If this does not work, please edit your question to show the relevant HTML and JavaScript sections.

Comment: I just checked your page and it is no longer refreshing (or posting the form). The HTML of the button has been updated to include "type=button". Has this issue been resolved?

Comment: It worked with  **type="button"** I have removed the type=button from the site. I just wanted to know why it was behaving like this. 


Thanks a lot Nico. :)